# CountryDropdownField - Setting default to what is set in setEmptyString()?

Tags: silverstripe

I am using the `CountryDropdownField`. I have set the empty string. It keeps defaulting to `United States` though. How I do I make it default to what is set in the empty string?

```
$fields = new FieldList(
    CountryDropdownField::create('Country')
        ->setEmptyString('-- Please choose a country --')
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following to the mysite_config\config.yml (then ensure a dev/build?full=1 is run) to achieve this...

```
CountryDropdownField:
  default_to_locale: false
  default_country: ''
```

Comment: Thanks Barry. It is not working for me with SSv3.4.1. Kindly improve your answer by giving the exact path of the file for _config.yml. I tried the above configuration in /mysite/_config/config.yml and /mysite/_config/_config.yml but I am still getting the default selected country "United States". I want to change to the first option i.e. -- Select country from the list --

Comment: Answer updated to confirm the exact file name along with a hint to ensure you dev build, apologise for any confusion as this is basic stuff all ss developers should be hardwired for after a little usage of the framework